# How to fix svg image to specific height and remain responsive?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting to create a simple responsible logo inside of a navbar. I've recreated the problem with [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjXpeB?editors=1100).

Essentially I have a `.logo` wrapper around an `<svg>` logo:

```
#navbar .logo {
  height: 80px;
}

#navbar .logo svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

At around 500-600px in width you can see that the SVG element box is much wider than the actual logo. I can fix this by removing the height rule on the `.logo` div. But then the SVG goes beyond 80px in height.

How can I constrain the navbar height to 80px and maintain the actual width of the SVG so that the logo remains flush against the left side of the container?

If I replace `width: 100%;` with `width: auto;`, the logo flushes to the left like I want, but then the `.logo` div is much larger than the SVG.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it [link](https://pixhost.to/show/291/76706452_captura.jpg) <--look at this screenshot

Comment: The problem was a little bit wider than that width. About 1.5 times that size. I think samuel got what I wanted though all I needed was a max width on the logo div, not the svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. I set a `max-width` to the div `.logo` and made the width of the `svg` to 100%.

Check this out: https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/LBzRwM?editors=1100

Comment: I was putting the `max-width` on the wrong element.